# Django: how to link additional data to choices, using radio buttons?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my projet, I'd like to create a minimalist shop page where the user can choose between items to buy. There is no data model used for this.

Simplified, the form looks like this:

```
class CardOrderForm(forms.Form):
    order = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ORDER_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

In another file:

```
ORDER_CHOICES = (
    ('CARDS_100', 'Pack de 100 cartes'),
    ('CARDS_200', 'Pack de 200 cartes'),
    ('CARDS_500', 'Pack de 500 cartes'),
```

After that, in views.py, I will charge the user according to the choice.

However, how would you define a price to be linked to the choices?
I don't want to write something ugly like this:

```
if form.order == 'CARDS_100':
    # charge 39€
elif form.order == 'CARDS_200':
    # charge 69€
... etc
```

Do you see a better alternative? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a `ORDER_CHOICES_TO_PRICES` mapping** which will give you the price for a particular order choice.

```
ORDER_CHOICES_TO_PRICES = {
    'CARDS_100': 39,
    'CARDS_200': 69,
    ...
}
```

Then in your views, you can just use this mapping to get the price.

```
price = ORDER_CHOICES_TO_PRICES[form.cleaned_data['order']] # will give you the price for a particular order
```

Comment: `form.order` does not exist. I think you was thinking of `form.cleaned_data['order']` ? Plus, you used `,` instead of `:` in your snippet. But in the end, it worked, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yeah i meant that and sorry for the typo!